# Remove small chunks of labels in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am new in MATLAB also in image processing, I am trying to locate a person frame by frame. so far I have labeled the cropped image (cropped using [PeopleDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.peopledetectorclass.html)) like this, now if I locate exact location of person like i.e. at which pixel location '1' start and end (I know this is not right logic).

All I want is to remove little chunks of white pixels at the right side of the person. I dont know how to do that. please suggest me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html):

```
bwareaopen(A, P)
```

This removes all objects that have fewer than `P` pixels from binary image `A`.

Answer (score 3):

use `regionprops`

```
>> props = regionprops( bwlabel( mask, 4 ), 'Area', 'PixelIdxList' );
>> smallRegions = [props(:).Area] < minNumPixels; % select the small regions
>> mask( [props( smallRegions ).PixelIdxList ] ) = 0; % reset small regions
```