# How can I remove/reassign small pixelregions (at edges) from color images? (MATLAB)

Tags: image, matlab, colors, image-segmentation, labeling

I have segmentation masks with indexed colors. Unfortunately there is (colored) noise at the edges of objects. At the transition from one color region to the next, there are small pixel regions in different colors, separating the two color regions (caused by converting transparent pixels at the edges).

[image: See image: Segmentation with Noise]

I want to remove this noise (with MATLAB) by assigning a color of one of the neighboring large regions. It doesn't matter, which one - main thing is to remove the small areas.
It can be assumed that small regions of ANY color may be removed in this way (reassign to neighboring large region).

In case of a binary image, I could use `bwareaopen` (suggested in this Q&A: [Remove small chunks of labels in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429545/remove-small-chunks-of-labels-in-an-image)). Converting the image to a binary image for each color might be a workaround, however this is costly (for many colors) and leaves the question of reassignment open. I hope there are more elegant ways to do this.

Comment: How did you assign the indexes in the first place? You shouldn't be using interpolation or anything that will yield invalid indices. Maybe take a step back and fix the assignment rather than post-processing the result.

Comment: That is an excellent idea, and if I'd done the labeling myself, I would have avoided transparency when segmenting the images. Since I have to work now with the given labels, that is not an option though :/

Comment: So do you have indexed values `[1, 2, 3]` for example?

Comment: Dilate a region with mask of other valid regions.

Comment: @Suever: Yes, the files are Indexed Color tiffs `[0, 1, 2, ...]`, with a shared colormap.

Comment: @MendiBarel: Interesting idea! Not yet sure how I would decide, which regions/colors to dilate though. I'll see whether I get it to work and will post an answer here if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following:

- Convert RGB to indexed image.
- Apply median filter on indexed map.
- Convert back to RGB

---

```
RGB = imread('GylzKm.png');

%Convert RGB to indexed image with 4 levels
[X, map] = rgb2ind(RGB, 4);

%Apply median filter on 4 levels images
X = medfilt2(X, [5, 5]);

%Convert indexed image back to RGB.
J = ind2rgb(X, map);

figure;imshow(J);
```

The black border is a little problematic.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this works like a charm! Since I already had indexed images, the first and last step were obsolete. I could remove artifacts as the black border shown in your picture by decreasing the kernel size (`X = medfilt2(X, [3, 3]);`). The only remaining problem were brown pixels between black and red areas. If I substitute all pixels indexed as black by white, brown noise is removed, too. Wondering why, as indexed colors shouldn't care about brown kinda being close to a mix of black/red. Maybe the problem is with the index order. (black = 0, brown = 1, green = 2, red = 4, white = 6, ...)

Comment: I was supersized I could find such a simple solution. The idea of using `medfilt2` came quickly, but realizing I can use `rgb2ind` for getting the closest color was kind of luck... How did you solve it without converting to RGB? Did you use `imapprox` or just `medfilt2`?

Comment: I just used `medfilt2`, since as mentioned before I already had indexed color images (so applying `rgb2ind` probably wouldn't work or change nothing).
Anyway: I like the medfilt2-idea. Thanks again :)